# CSS Menu does not appear over flash

Tags: css, flash, drop-down-menu, swfobject, open-flash-chart

I have a drop-down/multi-level CSS menu on a page. The menu however doesn't appear over a flash chart I have. **The apparent fix seems to be to put wmode:transparent (or opaque), but that doesn't work for me.** I have also tried setting the z-level in the CSS to very high values (2000) but that doesn't work either.

In addition, I'm using open-flash-chart-v2 to generate the chart. (though I don't think it matters, but it limits my ability to pass variables as I'm not using the embed or object tag directly).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("/ofc-library/open-flash-chart.swf", "chart", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", {"wmode" : "transparent"});
</script>
```

[Page showing problem](http://www.bcsfanpoll.com/graph/) (This doesn't currently show the z-index attempt to fix.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The wmode tag has not been set correctly.

Here is the correct code:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" style="visibility: visible;" id="chart" data="/ofc-library/open-flash-chart.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param value="transparent" name="wmode"/></object>
```

Here is your code:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/ofc-library/open-flash-chart.swf" id="chart" style="visibility: visible;"><param name="flashvars" value="wmode=transparent"/></object>
```

Specifically:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="wmode=transparent"/>
```

should be:

```
<param value="transparent" name="wmode"/>
```

Here is how to do it correctly (note the empty hash before the params. wmode is a param not a flashvar):

```
swfobject.embedSWF("/ofc-library/open-flash-chart.swf", "chart", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", {}, {"wmode" : "transparent"})
```

Comment: tip: only use wmode transparent if you truly need your SWF to be transparent. wmode opaque should work equally well for your needs and consumes much fewer system resources. it's also much less buggy than wmode transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using swfObject, try this:

```
 var so = new SWFObject("/ofc-library/open-flash-chart.swf", "chart", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
 so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
 so.write("flashcontent");
```